# Allow query strings in EE1?

Tags: ee1, querystring

Here's an oldie but goodie. Links from social sharing sites are coming back like this:

http://reliabilityweb.com/index.php/articles/start_executing_success_doesnt_stop_at_training/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Reliabilityweb+%28Reliabilityweb.com%29#When:15:03:50Z

The ? and everything that follows confuses EE1 and yields 'Invalid GET data'. I see there is a solution for EE2, but what about EE1? Nothing in the docs.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is due to %28 and %29 which stand for `(` and `)`.

You could hack EE to allow these characters but they are blocked as a precaution against code injection.

`utm` query values look like google analytics.  You probably don't care whether your campaign name as it appears in Google Analytics includes `(` and `)` -- so long as they are consistently reported.  So it would seem you could simply strip them out with a Rewrite Rule in Apache Server.